# Breaking ul li tree in 2 column

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I am having a strict two levels ul li structure. I want to display it in 2 columns as the tree is very long and want to occupy the right portion for better user friendliness. So far I have achieved this using css3 property `column-count`. I am getting the expected result but the problem is it is breaking a subtree which I am unable to prevent. Is there a css property which will work in combination with column-count or independently and allow me to split my tree in 2 column without breaking a sub-tree.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <ul>
       <li>asd
          <ul>
             <li>lmn</li>
             ...
          </ul>
       </li>
       <li>xyz
          <ul>
             <li>pqr</li>
             ...
          </ul>
       </li>
       ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#parent {
   column-count:2;
   -moz-column-count:2;
   -webkit-column-count:2
}
```

So far my jsfiddle looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/7WwK7/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change value `display` of `<li>` from default `list-item` to `inline-block` + `width:99%;`, and `<li>`s won't break anymore through `column`s.

if you still want the bullet , use a pseudo element to fake it.

http://jsfiddle.net/7WwK7/6/

Comment: Hey! thanks for the answer, but it didn't work when I added many `li's` inside one of the subtree. Check this - http://jsfiddle.net/7WwK7/4/ And I don't need bullet.

Comment: oh yes , it only works with FF, to include  others it is inline-block + width 90-100% http://jsfiddle.net/7WwK7/6/